# Finding a constant using joint conditional PMF

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Nick shops for statistics books for $H$ hours, where $H$ is a random variable, equally likely to be $1,2,3$ or $4$. The number of books $B$ he buys is random and depends on how long he shops according to the joint conditional PMF
$$Pr(B=b|H=h) = \frac{c}{h}, \text{ for } b= 1, . . . , h$$
for some constant $c$

**Problem:** Find a value for $c$

From the definition of joint conditional PMF
\begin{align*}
P_{B|H}(B=b|H=h) &= \frac{P_{B,H}(B=b,H=h)}{P_H(H=h)} \\
\frac{c}{h} &= \frac{P_{B,H}(B=b,H=h)}{P_H(H=h)} \\
\frac{c}{h} &= \frac{P_{B,H}(B=b,H=h)}{\frac{1}{4}} && \text{since $H$ is equally like to be $1,2,3,4$} 
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how to calculate $P_{B,H}(B=b,H=h)$ or if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum the equation you got over $b$ from $1$ to $h$. You get $h\frac c h=\frac {P(H=h)} {1/4}=1$. So $c=1$.